# Jquery how to append and serialize an array

Tags: jquery

I have a form that it's being serialized:

```
// save data
var data = $('#siteForm input').serialize();
```

Data will contain the following:

Site=asdf&StrDateUpdate=08%2F31%2F2016&StartingBR=1&EndingBR=1&HandsPlayed=1&ScreenShot=www.screenshoturl2.com

Now I have an array of strings:

```
var contents = $('#screenlist').html().split(/\n|\<br>/).filter(function(v) {
                            return /\w+/.test(v);
                        });
                        var links = {};

                        for (var k in contents) {
                            links[k] = contents[k];
                        }
```

And now I need to append `links` array into my data serialized content so my server can catch it.

> Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `$.param()`.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

> Create a serialized representation of an array, a plain object, or a
>   jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax
>   request...

```js
var obj   = {foo:'b a r',blah:'ha=lb'},
    query = $.param(obj);

$('#output').text(query);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```